# boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory() open_only fails on XP

Tags: c++, windows, boost

I have a two simple applications that use shared memory from `boost_1_55_0`.
`BoostCreate.exe` create the shared memory.
`BoostOpen.exe` open the created shared memory.
I built them with VS2008 and they work on Windows7/8.1, but on Windows XP `BoostOpen.exe` fails to open the shared memory .
This is `BoostCreate.exe` code:

```
using namespace boost::interprocess;
std::string shMemName("MySharedMem");
managed_shared_memory shMem = managed_shared_memory(create_only, shMemName.c_str(), 1000);
```

This is `BoostOpen.exe` code:

```
using namespace boost::interprocess;
std::string shMemName("MySharedMem");
try
{
  managed_shared_memory shMem = managed_shared_memory(open_only, shMemName.c_str());
}
catch(boost::interprocess::interprocess_exception& e)
{
    printf("Error opening %s\n", e.what());
}
```

The exception is: `The system cannot find the file specified`.
Trying `boost_1_59_0` I get some linker errors:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall boost::container::container_detail::has_member_function_named_construct<class boost::container::new_allocator<char> >::BaseMixin::construct(void)" (?construct@BaseMixin@?$has_member_function_named_construct@V?$new_allocator@D@container@boost@@@container_detail@container@boost@@QAEXXZ)
```

Comment: The linker error can be worked around by  building a debug build, or disabling optimization, it appears. Try that to see what the behaviour on Boost 1_59 is

Comment: Are you running the client in the same [session](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/07/24/sessions-desktops-and-windows-stations.aspx) ? Permissions and namespacing could lead to the map being invisible/inaccessible

Comment: Yes, using native Win32 `CreateFileMapping` and `OpenFileMapping`, I can create and open the same shared memory. Unfortunately here I am using `managed_shared_memory;;construct<T>` and it would require to rewrite a lot of code to use native API.

Comment: Same results as `Boost 1_55` with `Boost 1_59`

Comment: Can you trace down to what Win32 API's are failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BoostOpen.exe` was failing within the `CreateFileA` api call, returning -1 as handle value.
I noticed that on Windows7 the boost shared memory name was:

```
C:\ProgramData/boost_interprocess/1447248616/MySharedMem
```

while in XP was:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data/boost_interprocess//MySharedMem
```

It looked like a time stamp was missing in between the `//`.
I found that `get_bootstamp()` (tmp_dir_helpers.hpp) returns a empty `bootstamp.stamp` string on XP.
To avoid adding this empty timestamp, I commented line 19 in the \boost_1_55_0\boost\interprocess\detail\workaround.hpp

```
//#define BOOST_INTERPROCESS_HAS_KERNEL_BOOTTIME
```

and now with the name:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data/boost_interprocess/MySharedMem
```

it works both on Windows7 and XP.
Another solution is to leave line 19 and uncomment line 21:

```
#define BOOST_INTERPROCESS_BOOTSTAMP_IS_LASTBOOTUPTIME
```